How can I download the slides that a presenter is sharing in MS Teams?
I am in a MS Teams meeting. Someone presents slides. How can I download the slides that a presenter is sharing in MS Teams?
Example:


One can download the slides that a presenter is sharing in MS Teams after the meeting, in the recap tab:

This might require permissions:

